# What will be the final product when the above bridged compound is heated with concentrated sulfuric acid?

Tags: organic-chemistry, alcohols

[image: (1S,2S,4R,7S)-7-methylbicyclo[2.2.1]heptane-2,7-diol]

What will be the final product when the above compound ((1*S*,2*S*,4*R*,7*S*)-7-methylbicyclo[2.2.1]heptane-2,7-diol) is heated with concentrated sulfuric acid?

I know that the hydroxyl group in the bridgehead position cannot be protonated and removed to form a carbocation. The other hydroxyl group may be protonated and removed to form a carbocation I suppose. But after that what rearrangements will take place ? What will be the final product(s)?

Comment: There isn't any bridgehead hydroxyl in your compound.

Comment: Please have a look at [2-norbornyl cation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-Norbornyl_cation) and/or search for *non-classical cation* on this site.

Comment: @orthocresol I meant the OH on the top of the compound (in digram). That cannot be removed by protonation as a positive charge will be left behind on a non-planar center.

Comment: Why can't that carbon be planar? It's not a bridgehead, it's a bridge.

Comment: I fail to see why elimination from the tertiary alcohol should not be possible. The resulting cation could either add a nucleophile, which would result in the epimerization of that centre, or undergo elimination. The latter would yield an exomethylene group.

Comment: @orthocresol Okay, suppose I form a positive charge on the bridge, after removing OH, then what happens ? Can you tell me the steps after that ?

Comment: @KlausWarzecha I read the Wikipedia page you linked. Now my doubt is : Which OH will be protonated and removed first ?

Comment: @orthocresol Also, how do we know which OH will be removed first ? Will the tertiary OH be removed first as the tertiary carbocation is more stable ? And what next?

Comment: The carbocation resulting from the removal of hydroxyl group will not assume a planar structure,however pyramidal structure is possible but in my view the steric repulsions will outweigh the effect of the stabilising effect of a tertiary carbonation and hence the secondary hydroxyl group will be eliminated easily.

Comment: @aniline What can't it assume a planar structure ? Which steric effects are you talking about ?

Comment: Oh the hydroxyl group is in the bridge not on the bridgehead.ignore my previous comment.

Comment: @aniline Do you know how to get the final product? The steps?

Comment: Hmm... I wonder if forming the epoxide here is viable...

Answer (score 5):

Protonation of both $\ce{OH}$ groups and subsequent formation of the corresponding cations is possible.

- The tertiary cation will yield an exomethylene group
- The "secondary" non-classical cation leads to a $\ce{C=C}$ double bond in the ring. With other words, a norbornene is formed.

The combined eliminations will give 7-methylene bicyclo[2.2.1]hept-2-ene as the product.

In [*J. Am. Chem. Soc.*, **1973**, *95*, 7801-7813](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/ja00804a042), the same product was obtained by elimination from the tosylate of 7-hydroxy-7-methylnorborn-2-ene.